# How can i make Container shape like a Plane in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I`m trying to create a card or Container with borderRadius to change its top side shape like a plane Knob but i cannot make it i`m attaching a picture so please if any one know how to create this in flutter help me thanks

Shape:

[image]

Comment: Are you referring to economy part?

Comment: yes and no, i trying to create my whole container in the shape of a plane like in the image!

Comment: you can divide into two containers and have the UI. also you can maintain aspect but depends on the principal, would, it be width based UI?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh can you please share some code sample on how can i divide Containers?
btw i`m trying to achieve it with Stack Widget but its not giving me what i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play with CliPPath, change the control point value to make it perfect.

```dart
class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  const Test({super.key});

  @override
  State<Test> createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (p0, constaints) {
          final width = constaints.maxWidth;

          final double viewWidth = width * .8;
          return Center(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: SizedBox(
                width: viewWidth,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    //top Curve

                    ClipPath(
                      clipper: CurvePath(),
                      child: Container(
                        width: viewWidth,
                        height: viewWidth,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      width: viewWidth,
                      height: 1200,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CurvePath extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    return Path()
      ..moveTo(0, size.height)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(20, 0, size.width / 2, 0)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(size.width, 0, size.width, size.height)
      ..lineTo(0, size.height);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Also shapeBorder may help.

Comment: thanks now i can arrange it according to my needs thanks again!

Comment: Glad to help, you can find more about [Path](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Path-class.html)

Comment: thanks again i was looking for an article to learn more about Flutter Canvas this gonna help me really good!